# Using javascript custom button i need to create account and person account record

Tags: javascript, custom-button, account, person-accounts

like lead object i developed one custom button..when ever i click on button i need to create account and person account(person account is enabled in my org).

this my code. account is created but person account is not created

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js")}

var accnt = new sforce.SObject("Account");
accnt.Id = '{!Account.Id}';
accnt.Name = prompt('', '{!My_Leads__c.Lead_Name__c}');

var result = sforce.connection.create([accnt]);
if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
    alert('Account created successfully');

}
var cnt = new sforce.SObject("Account");
cnt.Name = prompt('', '{!My_Leads__c.Lead_Name__c}');

var result1 = sforce.connection.create([cnt]);
if (result1[0].getBoolean("success")){
    alert('Person contact created successfully');
    window.location.reload();
}
else {
    alert('Error : ' + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js")}

var accnt = new sforce.SObject("Account");
var recType=sforce.connection.query("SELECT name, id FROM RecordType" );
//alert(recType);
var records = recType.getArray("records");
//alert(records);
accnt.Name='{!My_Leads__c.Company__c}';
if(accnt.Name !="")
{
accnt.RecordTypeId = records[0].Id;
//alert(records[0].Id);

accnt.Id = '{!Account.Id}';
accnt.Name = prompt('','{!My_Leads__c.Company__c}');
accnt.OwnerId='{!My_Leads__c.OwnerId}';

var result = sforce.connection.create([accnt]); 
if(result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
{ 
alert('Account created successfully');

}
var cnt= new sforce.SObject("Contact"); 
cnt.Id = '{!Contact.Id}';
cnt.OwnerId='{!My_Leads__c.OwnerId}';
cnt.AccountId=result[0].id;
cnt.lastName = prompt('','{!My_Leads__c.Lead_Name__c}');

var result = sforce.connection.create([cnt]);
 if(result[0].getBoolean("success"))
{ 
alert('contact created successfully'); 
window.location.reload();

}

else{
  alert('Error : '+result);
}
}
else
{
accnt.RecordTypeId=records[1].Id;
//alert(records[1].Id);
accnt.Id = '{!Account.Id}';
accnt.LastName = prompt('','{!My_Leads__c.Lead_Name__c}');
accnt.OwnerId='{!My_Leads__c.OwnerId}';

var result = sforce.connection.create([accnt]); 
if(result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
{ 
alert('Account created successfully');

}
else
{
 alert('Error : '+result);
}
}

Comment: I need to delete this records after converted ?how to do it

Comment: After convert my lead object records i need to delete those records automatically

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a person account, you'll have to set the recordtype id.

```
cont.RecordTypeId = '<person account record type id>';
```

You can hardcode the record type Id, use a [Label](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm), use a [Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm?search_text=custom%20setting) or query for it.